# twitter api getting tweets(posts)

Tags: twitter

is there a way to get tweets from some specific user and since some time of period?
I see that statuses/user_timeline has the screen_name param which I can search for specific user's tweets but can't filter these tweets by date created.
so if I want to get this user's past 1 week tweets what are some ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to use [GET statues/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) and `page` backwards in time until you either run out of results or get back statuses that are older then the time range of interest.